# Why Java class default constructor is not called upon declaration?

Tags: java

Java has default constructor but is not functioning in the same way as C++.

In C++ default constructor is implicitly called when the object is declared so no need to explicit "new" it. But in Java an object must be explicitly initialized. Is there a special reason for that? Was there any feature request for this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? That said, I'm not sure there's any answer here besides "Java is not C++ and it works the way it works"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only if the C++ declaration is creating an object on the stack. All Java objects are heap-based, so that's not an option. In both languages the constructor is called when a new object is created.

```
// C++
Obj obj;  // stack
Obj* pObj = new Obj;  // heap

// Java
Obj obj = new Obj();  // heap (stack not possible)
```

Comment: Exactly. In Java, you don't declare an object, but a reference to an object.

Comment: I thought C++ object is kinda like a reference on the heap too? Maybe I am wrong, but can you please explain a bit?

Comment: The latter is a pointer to an object on the heap, but the former is an object on the stack.

Comment: @texasbruce Not even close. A C++ pointer to an object can be thought of as a kind of reference (not to be confused with regular C++ references), but it can point to the heap or a previously stack-allocated object. And you can do `class Foo { Bar _bar; } ... Foo *foo = new Foo();` where Foo is allocated on the heap, but `bar` will get initialised with the default constructor for `Bar`. So the distinction between stack allocation and heap allocation isn't really relevant; it's whether you're dealing with object pointers or object values (which Java doesn't have).

Comment: So Java reference is always allocated on the heap but C++ object is allocated on the stack(like struct?) and pointer is on the heap?

Comment: Well, the Java *object* is allocated on the heap; the reference to it is on the stack.

In C++ any the reference/pointer location and the object location are independent, and could be on the stack or heap. Let me know if you want code examples for each, though I'm not sure how much they add.

Answer (score 2):

Technically,

> In C++ default constructor is implicitly called when the object is declared

is not incorrect, but incomplete. If an object has a user-defined default constructor, you can't only declare it. The point of declaration is also a definition and initialization.

In Java, a reference can be `null`, whereas in C++ it can't. Only pointers can be `NULL` in C++. So there's different semantics.

```
JavaObject o = null; //valid Java
                     //invalid C++
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java construct:

```
MyClass myObject;
```

is equivalent (-ish) to the following C++:

```
MyClass *myObject;
```

not to:

```
MyClass myObject;
```

There is no Java equivalent to the latter.